# Scale Image to Size of Other Element Withing the Same Parent <div>

Tags: html, css, scaling

This is not a very complicated problem, but I can't figure out an answer or find something on the web.

I have two elements within on parent `<div>`:

- an image (contained in a separate div with float:left or float:right)
- text

The width of the parent div is fixed to 600px.
The height is variable.

I want the size of the height of the image to match the height of the text block. The full-size image is usually larger than the text block.

To match two divs I usually use a wrapper div and adapt the height of the wrapped divs using "100%". This does, however, adjust the size to the size of the bigger one of the inner divs. In my case, the div with the image would, in most cases, be bigger than the text block, so a wrapper div is no option. Using a fixed height or max-height is also no option.

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left;"><img src="..." /></div>
  <div><p>some text probably smaller than the full-sized image</p></div>
</div>
```

tl;dr: I need to adjust the height of the first inner div containing the image to the height of the second inner div containing the text no matter if the text is bigger or smaller than the full-sized image.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf1gmor/1/

By the way, the text does not HAVE to be contained in a separate div. The `<p>` is enough, but I think a container is required to solve this problem.

Comment: So what is supposed to happen to the picture in case its container is smaller than the img?

Comment: @connexo The div containing the image has no fixed size (it only contains the image, and the image always has 100% of the divs size). Its height should be the height of the second inner div cointainer.

Comment: please provide a code snippet (JsFiddle?) that reproduces the issue, so it would be easier to  help you...

Comment: @RonenCypis: Thanks for the suggestion, I just did that.

Comment: if the text block is shorter than the native height of the image, what should happen? show only part of the image? distort ("stretch") it?

Comment: @RonenCypis Scale it (while keeping the aspect ratio) which should happen automatically if I could somehow tell the <div> containing the image to always have the same height as <div> containing the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the image as a `background-image` for the containing `div` and get rid of the `div` with the `img` inside it.

The `.container` would get `padding-left: 50%;` to keep the text inside it on the right side, and `background-size: 50% 100%` so the background image will take 50% of its width, and 100% of its height (determined by the text block...)

here is how:

https://jsfiddle.net/ronency/hxcdd5az/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-container">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg") left top no-repeat;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 50%;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}

.text-container {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem with this solution is that I have to adjust a fixed width percentage to the background image which changes the aspect ratio and reduces flexibility. I'd like, for example, a rectangular image to be resized 100x100px if the text block is 100px in height (the text then uses the remaining total width - 100px space), and a 800x400px image to 200x100px (the text then has 100px less space available, but the aspect ratio of the image is maintained).

Comment: You will be lost down the rabbit hole with this requirements. If the Image's width is a result of the text height, and the text's height is the result of the remaining width from the containerWidth-imageWidth... Do you see where this is going...?

Comment: Using this solution, you can fix the `padding-left` & `background-size` to be fixed width (px), and still maintain the aspect ratio... but you CAN'T have a circular condition like you just described...

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I guess without JavaScript there is no solution for this problem without compromising in terms of flexibility. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: If this answers your above question, as described, accepting it is the right way to go :-)